# Sequelize / Postgres. Date Array Input Being Read as Text Array

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to seed my database, and one of my model's attributes is of type Date Array(timestamp with time zone). I end up getting this error:

```
column "myDate" is of type timestamp with time zone[] but expression is of type text[]
```

It works fine with a date type, but for some reason, only the Date Array is being interpreted as a text array.

I'm seeding the "myDate" field with something like this:

```
myDate: [new Date(), new Date()]
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
myDate: Sequelize.literal(`ARRAY['2004-10-19 10:23:54+02']::timestamp with time zone[]`)
```

Which is a slight variation on this issue:
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11541

(note the differenece in syntax between my answer and the one in the github issue. The latter didn't work for me.)

Answer (score 0):

Or a more simpler form

```
myDate: '{2004-10-19 10:23:54+02}'
```

please note the curly brases are inside the quotes.

you could add even more values ex.

```
myDate: '{2004-10-19 10:23:54+02, 2010-13-19 10:23:54+02}'
```

Hope this helps.